# ARM assembly appending multiple bits

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, cpu-registers

The aim of my program is to take the value in register 0 and copy it in the form
'1011' into register 1.

**EDIT I did not initially make this clear, not to be achieved with a simple `mov`, the goal was to isolate each bit and reconstruct from that point**

I am using logical shifts to isolate each of the bits in combination with an AND
mask within register 4 to detect weather or not a 1 is present.

As it stand the code exits normally but the issue is every time I loop to perform a new and, the value of the previous and is pushed out of register 1.

In the debugger the value of R1 goes , 1, 0, 1 , 1

When want I am looking for is: 1, 10, 101, 1011

Here is the .s file

```
            .global _start

_start:
        mov     R0,#0b1011
        mov     R4,#1   @Will act as a mask
        mov     R5,#3   @Shifter
        bl      movregs
        mov     R7,#1
        svc     0

movregs:
        and     R1,R4,R0,lsr R5 @Isolates each bit for moving
        subs    R5,#1    @Decrements the shifter
        bge     movregs

        bx      LR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to involved using a register `mov  R4,#1` as a bit mask,
checking the presence of a 1 with `and  R1,R4,lsr R5` finally `orr R0,R1,lsl #4` with the left logical shift being decremented each time.

Comment: You could show your actual final code in your answer. This could attract some useful comments, suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realise that a simple
`mov R1, R0`
gives you what you want?

As to your example, no surprise it's not doing what you want - the AND opcode destroys the previous content of R1 each time. Try taking pen & paper and just go through your loop  writing down the registers' values on each step.

Comment: Actually the answer was not as simple as that, 
I ended up using left logical shifts of different grades and then ORRing the next number that I wanted to add, this way the past numbers would not be forgotten

Comment: `mov R1, R0` defeats the point of the entire exercise, The aim was to isolate each bit and then reconstruct it in another register

Comment: @BG45: A better exercise would be copying a bitfield from one register to another, i.e. replacing a range of bits in one reg with bits from another, but keeping the rest.  (You'd normally use AND to clear the destination bytes, then another AND to isolate the bitfield, and ORR to insert them.  Or modern ARM has some bitfield insert/extract instructions.)